# Jquery serialize selected form

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to select a particular form to serialize?  I have multiple forms on my CF page.  I want to select a particular form, submit ajax post, then select a second form and submit an ajax post.

```
$('.CSubmitSurvey').live('click', function(e) {
        var strCandidateSurveyForm = $('#sendSurveysCandidate').serialize();
        alert (strCandidateSurveyForm);
        IndividualNumber = document.getElementById('sendSatTo2').value;
        companyNumber = document.getElementById('companyID').value;
        surveyNumber = document.getElementById('surveyID').value;
        resendSurvey = document.getElementById('ReSendYN').value;
        RefID = document.getElementById('RefID').value;
        ClientCandidate = document.getElementById('ClientCandidate').value;
        EmailOverride = document.getElementById('EmailOverride').value;
        SendSatEmail = $('input:radio[name=SendSatEmail]:checked').val()
        //alert(SendSatEmail);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'actSendSurveys.cfm',
            data:  '<cfoutput>indivNum=' + IndividualNumber + '&board_type=#board_type#&jobid=' + jobid + '&companyid=' + companyNumber + '&resendyn=' + resendSurvey + '&SurveyNumber=' + surveyNumber + '&RefID=' + RefID + '&ClientCandidate=' + ClientCandidate + '&SendSatEmail=' + SendSatEmail + '&EmailOverride=' + EmailOverride</cfoutput>,
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(response1, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //alert('success');
                if (ClientCandidate == 'client'){
                    ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('ClientSurveyGrid',true);
                }
                else {
                    ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('CandSurveyGrid',true);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Automatically? or when a user does something. Ie submits it

Comment: when they click on a button on the form.

Comment: Yes , Their is a Way !... You need to show your code.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you doing things like `document.getElementById('ReSendYN').value;` instead of `$('#ReSendYN').val()`

Comment: If we can stick to the question, I can get rid of those.

Comment: On a different note, I would remove the .live() function, which is deprecated, and replace it with .on()

Comment: Doesn't work.  The event never fires.
$('.CSubmitSurvey').on('click',function(){

Comment: Well, so much for "Yes, there is a way!..."

Comment: There is...console.log is your friend

Answer (score 0):

For all your buttons, just apply a Jquery click handler...
If the button is not part of the form.

```
$('#button1').click(function{
var data = $('#form1').serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: your url,
     data: data,
     success: function(){ your functions}
   });
});

    $('#button2').click(function{
    var data = $('#form2').serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: your url,
     data: data,
     success: function(){ your functions}
   });
});
```

If the button is part of the form, you can just do an Jquery onsubmit, with prevent default...

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var data = $(this).serialize();
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: your url,
    data: data,
    success: function(){ your functions}
  });
});
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm doing.

Comment: If I change the button to a submit, it submits the entire page. Either way, The variable that hold the serialize results is empty.

Comment: @user990016 It doesn't look like you're calling `preventDefault()`, which is what stops the button from submitting.

Comment: $('#sendSurveysCandidate').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 var strCandidateSurveyForm = $(this).serialize();
 alert (strCandidateSurveyForm);

Comment: FYI;
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: what happens if you console.log the serilized data.  It it not showing anything?

Comment: If I use;
var strCandidateSurveyForm = $('form').serialize();
I get ALL of the form elements.  I guess I'll just have to work with that.

Comment: Oh...that tells me that youre not seperating the forms with <form></form> and theyre just seperated <fieldsets>

Comment: I have the entire page in a <cfform></cfform> and a <form></form> on a bound div and another <form></form> on another bound div.